# Trying to splice items from my array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to splice on a DoubleClick event an item from my list(inventory) but something is not working as I want it. Would be nice if someone could be so kind and help me out to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. For the Info: when I try to slice an item it gets sliced but it is every time the first item and the second item loses all the content inside:

```
    function Inventory() {
    const [datas, setData] = useState([
      {
        id: 1, 
        label: "Sword",
        itemname: "grey_sword",
        pieces: 1,
        type: "weapon",
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        label: "Knife",
        itemname: "grey_knife",
        pieces: 1,
        type: "weapon",
      },
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const getItems = (data) => {
        setData(data);
      } // this section is for something else
    }, [datas]);

    const deleteItem = (index) => {
      const test = ([], datas)
      test.splice(index, 1)
      setData([{test : datas}]);
    }



    const renderItem= (data, index) => {
      return (
        <Item
          key={data.id}
          id={data.id}
          type={data.type}
          label={data.label}
          index={index}
          name={data.itemname}
          pieces={data.pieces}
          deleteItem={deleteItem}
        />
      )
    }

    return (
        <div className="inventory-holder">
            <div className="inventory-main">
              <div className="inventory-information">
                <div className="inventory-title">
                  Inventory
                </div>
                <div className="inventory-weight-info">
                  0.20 kg / 1.00 kg
                </div>
                <div className="inventory-buttons">
                  <button className="refresh-button" tabIndex="-1"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRedo} /></button>
                  <button className="close-button" tabIndex="-1"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="items-holder">
                <div>{datas.map((data, i) => renderItem(data, i))}</div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Inventory;
```

and that would be the Item:

```
const Item = ({ index, id, type, label, name, pieces, deleteItem }) => {
  
    const useItem = e => {
      const type = e.target.getAttribute("itemType");
      const index = e.target.getAttribute("data-index");
      const pieces = e.target.getAttribute("itempieces");
      console.log(type + " " + index + " " + pieces )
      if(parseInt(pieces) <= 1){
        deleteItem(parseInt(index));
      }
    }

    return(
        <div data-index={id} onDoubleClick={useItem} className="inventory-item" itemType={type} itemname={name} itemlabel={label} itempieces={pieces}>
            <img className="item-pic" src={chosedtype} ></img>
            <div className="item-label">{label}</div>
            <div className="item-number-pieces">{pieces}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Item;
```

Comment: never saw -  `const test = ([], data)` before - what's that?

Comment: @andymccullough https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: nice, didnt _realise_ it was a thing, but it makes sense when thinking of the parenthesis in a for loop.  Still, what's it doing in this example? i.e. `[]` by itself isn't much of an operation, neither is `datas`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

[Array::splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does an in-place mutation.

> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or
> replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements *in place*.

The main issue here is state mutation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

`const test = ([], datas)` ends up saving the state reference `data` to `test`, which is then mutated by `test.splice(index, 1)`, and then strangely enough is overwritten back into state differently `setData([{ test: datas }]);`.

## Solution

A common pattern is to use [array::filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead and filter on the index. `filter` returns a new array.

```
const deleteItem = (index) => {
  setData(datas => datas.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you helped. This helped me out for the moment. @Nico_ 's method combined resolved my next problem with the Index. Thank you guys :D

Answer (score 1):

Your Item is way too complicated:

You can directly use the props without passing them through your `div`.

```
const Item = ({ index, id, type, label, name, pieces, deleteItem }) => {
  
    const useItem = () => {
      console.log(type + " " + index + " " + pieces )
      if(pieces <= 1){
        deleteItem(index);
      }
    }

    return(
        <div data-index={id} onDoubleClick={useItem} className="inventory-item">
            <img className="item-pic" src={chosedtype} ></img>
            <div className="item-label">{label}</div>
            <div className="item-number-pieces">{pieces}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Item;
```

Then your `deleteItem` function doesn't do what you want:

```
const deleteItem = (index) => {
  const test = ([], datas); //test = datas;
  test.splice(index, 1); // test = test without the item at the index
  setData([{test : datas}]);//data = [{test: datas}] so an array with an object with the property test = datas (the original array).
}
```

You should change your `deleteItem` to something like:

```
const deleteItem = (index) => {
    const newArray = datas.filter((item, i) => i !== index);
    setData(newArray);
}
```